# Sequelize exclude password from user association

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a users table that I have associated with an assets table by the user ID. I created the hasMany association from the users table to the assets table and the belongsTo association from the assets table to the users table. When I perform a findAll on the assets table I get the proper user information back based on the associations made. The problem is that the user record has the password hash and other properties coming with it that I done want. I only want the name coming with this association.

I have tried using the attributes tag inside the association but that didn't work.

```
Model.associate = (models) => {
    Model.belongsTo(models.User, { 
        as: 'user'
    });
}

Model.associate = (models) => {
    Model.hasMany(models.Asset);
}
```

If I can exclude columns, I would only expect to see the user's first name and last name come back from the users table.

Comment: The `attributes`  is used on the query, inside the association. Check [this](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html#attributes) for an example.

Comment: Ya i saw that example and figured I was misusing it. I am doing a findAll without passing anything but an include: { all: true }. I was trying to not have to specify it in each query where I reference the user table. Is there a global way to remove it from its associations?

Comment: @Ellebkey I've tried variations of the below in the association. None work.

    Model.belongsTo(models.User, { 
        as: 'user',
        // attributes: {
        //     exclude: [
        //         'user.email'
        //     ],
        // },
        attributes: {
            include: [
                'email'
            ],
        },
        // attributes: [
        //     'user.email'
        // ],
        constraints: false 
    });

Comment: can you please update your question with the query son I can see better what are you doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify attributes like this
`attributes: ['firstname', 'lastname']`

So the query would be something like

```
const assets = await asset.findAll({
attributes: ['attributes that you want to be included for assets table'],
include: [{
   model: User,
   attributes: ['firstname', 'lastname'],
 }]
})
```